# Navigation Bar Button

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

When I am putting two right bar buttons in my navigation bar at that time those two buttons are visible but they have a top border means I don't want that border.

I am creating those buttons in my frame and assigning that frame to the navigation bar. How do I hide that frame border?

My code is as below:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnAdd = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(Add)];

UIBarButtonItem *btnEdit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit"
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                               target:self
                                                               action:@selector(Edit)];

UIToolbar *rightToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 46)];
rightToolBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
rightToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:40.0/255.0 green:48.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:0.0];
NSArray *buttonsRight = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnEdit, btnAdd, nil];
[rightToolBar setItems:buttonsRight];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightToolBar];
```

Comment: can you please provide a screen shot or some code related to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnAdd = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(Add)];
```

instead of using

```
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
```

Comment: but in that button is not looking fancy.

Comment: you can use a custom button here with an image.

Comment: means that plain button looks too big and not good to see in user interface

Comment: I dont want to use image i am using simple text as Add and Edit of two buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Set frameborder="0" in Frame tag it will disable frame.

And if you link a button and it shows the border then use css to rewrite the link properties:

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

For help read http://www.w3schools.com/css